# Getting (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, bluehost

I'm trying to call an API in the back-end, but I just keep getting a connection refused error. The back-end is inside a tomcat server deployed in BlueHost; the framework is spring-boot; its war file is already deployed in webapp folder; and I've already included the following filter in **web.xml** to allow for CORS

```
<filter>
                <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>cors.allowed.orgins</param-name>
                        <param-value>*</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
                        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
                        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
                        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
                        <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

Since I believe CORS is already enabled by default in Spring-boot, I didn't bother to define cors configuration bean file; even when I did, I was still receiving the error. I also made sure that my client request didn't include any illegal headers. However, it's doing a pre-flight request with **Content Type**. It's the following:

```
let httpReq = {
        method: type,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        referrer: window.location.href, // https://web.dev/referrer-best-practices/
        referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        cache: "default",
        redirect: "error"
    };


await fetch("http://localhost:8080" + api, httpReq)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
```

I restarted apache and tomcat several times, still nothing. I was also unable to see any helpful logs from Tomcat, and I also made sure that the process is still working with **netstat**. I'm lost on what to do. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was stemming from a misconfigured include file in httpd.conf and a misconfigured pathing inside my pom.xml.